# Why does Wifi in master mode perform worse than in managed mode

Tags: network-manager, ap-hotspot

I set up my Ubuntu's wifi adapter to *master mode* (using Network manager).

I find that a client in the other side of the house (same floor) can not connect. On the other hand, when my Ubuntu box is in *client mode* it can connect to an AP of the same distance. It seems to me that the card has some limitation when in master mode.

Any clue?

Wifi adapter intel 7260, Ubuntu 14.04, driver iwlwifi

Answer (score 0):

When your wireless card is in master mode it acts as an access point and it actively transmits a signal. When your wireless card is in client mode or managed mode then it listens to signals and tries to match a suitable one. Usually wireless cards built-in into devices like laptops are limited in signal strength either in the hardware or in the software and they are tiny and lack an antenna of a reasonable size. Regular consumer routers usually are not limited in signal strength or are limited in a wrong way because they're built in a different country and they do have a big antenna. All this allows consumer routers to produce a stronger signal and their range is larger. So your observation is pretty normal. Also there are certain problems regarding the wireless frequency and the type and number of other wireless networks in the area.